# Not removing elements from the ListView when changing the dataset

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating an Android application which lets user to select the available sensors in the device, list the the  selected sensors with the actual sensor readings.

Here I use a custom adapter extending the `BaseAdaptor` class.
I asked a question on updating the list view realtime when dataset is changing and I was able to fix it.

Method I used to fix it:-

1. Define a public class which has 2 public fields to store data. A hashMap and a List (To be used for Adapter)
2. When the sensor is changed, put the sensor value and the sensor name to a hashmap and send a broadcast.
3. In the broadcast receiver class, if there are previous records in the list, clear it and put the readings to the list.

I pass the adapter to the sensor reading class so that I call `adapter.notifydataSetChanged()` when sensor changed.

Here is the UI workflow.
[image: Select sensor dialog]

[image: Selected sensor list]

Here are my source codes.

1. Sensor reader class. (`RealtimeSensor` is a class which stores the sensor data)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       RealTimeSensor realTimeSensor = new RealTimeSensor();
       realTimeSensor.setName(AvailableSensors.getType(event.sensor.getType()).toUpperCase());

       realTimeSensor.setValueX(event.values[0] + "");
       realTimeSensor.setValueY(event.values[1] + "");
       realTimeSensor.setValueZ(event.values[2] + "");

       TempStore.sensorDataMap.put(AvailableSensors.getType(event.sensor.getType()), realTimeSensor);

       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("sensorDataMap");
       context.sendBroadcast(intent);

       adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```
2. Broadcast receiver class

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       TempStore.realTimeSensors.clear();
       TempStore.realTimeSensors.addAll(TempStore.sensorDataMap.values());
   }
   ```
3. `onDialogPositiveClick` method

   ```
   SensorViewAdaptor adaptor1 = new                                                                          SensorViewAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), TempStore.realTimeSensors);

       sensorReader = new RealTimeSensorReader(this, adaptor1);

       for (Sensor s : sensors) {
           sensorManager.registerListener(sensorReader, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
       }


       realTimeSensorChangeReceiver.updateOnChange(adaptor1);
       listView.setAdapter(adaptor1);
   ```
4. The adapter class

   ```
   public class SensorViewAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {


   private Context context;
   private List<RealTimeSensor> data;

   public SensorViewAdaptor(Context context, List<RealTimeSensor> data) {
       this.context = context;
       this.data = data;

   }


   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return data.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return data.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ViewHolder holder;

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View view;

       if (convertView == null) {
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_sensor_values, parent, false);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
           holder.valuesX = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.X);
           holder.valuesY = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Y);
           holder.valuesZ = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Z);
           view.setTag(holder);
       } else {
           view = convertView;
           holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
       }

       RealTimeSensor data = this.data.get(position);

       holder.name.setText(data.getName());
       holder.valuesX.setText(data.getValueX());
       holder.valuesY.setText(data.getValueY());
       holder.valuesZ.setText(data.getValueZ());

       return view;

   }


   private class ViewHolder {
       public TextView name;
       public TextView valuesX;
       public TextView valuesY;
       public TextView valuesZ;
   }
   ```

   }

My problem is, when I deselect one of the selected sensors, it does not remove from the view. 
What would be the reason for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: when you are deselecting the sensor are you removing that from the adapter's list too?

Comment: btw I think its better to send data to the broadcast reciever in the intent extras rather than store access data from the static variable

Comment: @Bhargav Yes I clear the list and copy the new values.

Comment: Thank you very much Bhargav.... That was the problem. Not removing the unselected sensors from the list. There is another list which stores the user preferences. I have not removed the unselected from it. Now the problem is ok. :-)

Comment: well select it as the right answer then :) hepls me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are deselecting the sensor are you removing that from the adapter's list too?